# What is the alternative to using PageBlock in Visualforce for creating a form?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I need to create a form in a visualforce page and use slds to style it. I know we can't use slds in apex:inputField and apex:pageBlock. If I dont use pageBlock I'm not able to see the label for each field. How to get it to work? Is there an alternative way?

```
<div style="slds-form-element" id="modalbody">
          <apex:pageBlock>
              <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:inputText styleClass="slds-input" required="true" label="{!$ObjectType.CA_Additional_Information__c.fields.First_Name__c.label}" value="{!creditApplicantRecord.First_Name__c}"/>
                <apex:inputText styleClass="slds-input" required="true" label="{!$ObjectType.CA_Additional_Information__c.fields.Last_Name__c.label}" value="{!creditApplicantRecord.Last_Name__c}"/>
                <apex:inputText styleClass="slds-input" required="true" label="{!$ObjectType.CA_Additional_Information__c.fields.Phone_No__c.label}" value="{!creditApplicantRecord.Phone_No__c}"/>
              </apex:pageBlockSection>
          </apex:pageBlock>
    </div>
```

Comment: did you try to `standardStylesheets="false"` or `lightningStylesheets="true"`

Comment: Yes. lightningStyleSheets is set to true. I've even added <apex:slds/>. The thing is that I can't see the label of the field without pageblock.

Comment: But you can use `{!$ObjectType.Account.fields.Name.Label}` to getthe field label

Comment: But the label is not showing up on the page if I dont include the fields inside a pageblock. Actually I used apex:outputLabel for the labels now. That is working

Comment: If it solves your problem then you can accept the answer and close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use table/ div to create custom UI. To display a label with the field you can use `{!$ObjectType.Account.fields.Name.Label}`. Here you can change your object and field API name.